# Comparación de Datos de dos arreglos

Tags: php, sql-server

tengo dos arreglos que quiero comparar.

```
$arreglo1 = array($a1);


$arreglo2 = array($a2);
```

los dos arreglos contienen valores similares por ejemplo
contiene los siguientes datos

```
arreglo1 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10


arreglo2
1
2
4
7
9
10
```

estoy aplicando esto para compararlos

```
if($arreglo1 == $arreglo2){
 echo "a1";
 echo "b2";
}else{
echo"";
}
```

lo hace bien hasta que el primer a1 es diferente a2
lo que imprime es lo siguiente

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
```

a lo que quiero llegar

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3
4 -> 4
5
6
7 -> 7
8
9 -> 9
10 ->10
```

gracias por su atención y espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: ¿Por qué la etiqueta de `sql-server`?

Comment: por que lo que contiene los arreglos son dos consultas sql-server

Comment: ¿Hubiera sido posible hacer un JOIN en el servidor?

Comment: posiblemente si pero no tengo acceso a la BD

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si alguna de estas respuestas han aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarlas para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres con `in_array()` asi:

```
<?php
$arreglo1 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$arreglo2 = array(1,2,4,7,9,10);

foreach($arreglo1 as $num) {
    if(in_array($num,$arreglo2)) {
        echo $num . "->" . $num . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo $num . "<br>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Justo al publicar me apareció tu respuesta. Qué curioso, hemos pensado prácticamente igual ;)

Answer (score 0):

¿Algo así?

```
<?php

$a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$b=[1,2,4,7,9,10,];

foreach($a as $i){
    echo '<br>'.$i;
    if(in_array($i,$b))
        echo ' -> '.$i; 
}

?>

1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3
4 -> 4
5
6
7 -> 7
8
9 -> 9
10 -> 10
```